# Notes about participants

Tags: civievent, custom-fields, profile, participants

We need to fill some information about people that registered to specific event, for example room number where they will stay. Is it possible to store additional information about participants so that they won't see it? Personally I found the note field on the event registration screen for some participant. We could use it but it doesn't appear in the event reports. So I can't see the full list of participants with that field.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add Custom Fields specifically to Participant records and you can be more specific than just 'all participants' since the options provided are

- Participants
- Participants (Event Name)
- Participants (Event Type)
- Participants (role)

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right direction, participant notes are intended for this. But as you say, seems there is no way to show this field info on an event report.

Exists an improvement registered on [CRM-20236
Include "Note" field of Registration record in event participant reports](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20236) that would do what you want. If this is important for you and you don't have skills or resources to develop it, maybe [Paid issue queue](https://civicrm.org/paid-issue-queue)  could be a good way to achieve this.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Is there any other way to resolve my problem? Maybe I can create profile or custom field? I tried to create a profile for that but it didn't appear anywhere.

Comment: Seems that improvement was merged for 5.8 release (https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/13029).

Answer (score 0):

Since CiviCRM 5.8.0, participant notes column appear on the Event Participant Listing report.