# Participant's Notes is not available in Reports

Tags: civievent, civireport

I use Civi 4.7.27 on Drupal.

In the edit event registration dialog for a participant, there is a field for 'Notes' about this participant.

How can one add this 'Notes' field in a participants report? It does not appear in the 'Columns' tab of the report.

Comment: A similar question here https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/24370/notes-about-participants

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach we take in most installs is to add a participant custom field called something like 'registration notes'. This field can also double as a special request field that we use on front end registrations if you like. Then in reports you can have the user's requests and internal notes in the same column.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - that field is not there in stock CiviCRM; When I run into this I usually install Fuzion's [Extended Reports extension](https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.extendedreport). When the field is still not there in any of the Extended Report templates, then I add a field/PR for that Extension.

Here's an example of when I wanted to add in a handy link to the participant record and also add in the Source field:
https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.extendedreport/pull/55